# инструкции в python

Tags: python

Если инструкции - команды в Python.
То строка `print("Hello")` тоже будет инструкцией?
`print()` - встроенная функция.
можно ли print назвать инструкцией.
столкнулась с понятием "инструкция if", поэтому возник данный вопрос.

Comment: Что вы называете инструкцией? Что командой?

Comment: одно и то же называю. команду, называю инструкцией. инструкцию командой.

Comment: Что вы называете инструкцией?

Comment: Скажите, а какая практическая цель в этом вашем вопросе? ...

Comment: столкнулась сегодня с понятием "инструкция if", поэтому запуталась немного. Подумала, что неправильно понимаю понятие инструкции .До этого, например, запись print("Hello") - считала за инструкцию. если бы увидела запись инструкция if 5>3: вопросов бы не возникло, посчитала за команду....а тут if,да ещё один, да ещё написано инструкция....Такая логика....странная немного)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, строка `print("Hello")` **является инструкцией**.

---

*Почему?*

Согласно официальной документации [The Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html), русский перевод [Справочник по языку Python](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/reference/index.html).

---

*Подробнее:*

Для этой документации, инструкциями (statements) являются

- или **простые инструкции** ([7. Простые операторы](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/reference/simple_stmts.html), [7. Simple statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html)),
- или **составные инструкции** ([8. Составные операторы](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/reference/compound_stmts.html), [8. Compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html)).

Все типы простых и составных инструкций в этой документации перечисленны.

- К составным инструкциям относятся такие как `if`, `while`, `for` - это не ваш случай.
- **Вызов функции** в перечислении простых инструкций как *отдельный тип* не находится.

Но там находится тип **«инструкция-выражение»** ([7.1. Операторы выражений](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/reference/simple_stmts.html#exprstmts), [7.1. Expression statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements)). Он определен так:

```
expression_stmt    ::= starred_expression
starred_expression ::= expression | (starred_item ",")* [starred_item]
```

причем в типе `expression` (выражение, см. [6. Выражения](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/reference/expressions.html), [6. Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html)) находится `primary` (основный, см. [6.3. Праймериз](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/reference/expressions.html#primaries), [6.3. Primaries](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#primaries)), определенный как

```
primary ::=  atom | attributeref | subscription | slicing | call
atom    ::=  identifier | literal | enclosure
        ...
call    ::=  primary "(" [argument_list [","] | comprehension] ")"
```

**К последнему принадлежит и ваш вызов функции `print("Hello")`.**

Comment: спасибо за помощь. вы полностью объяснили непонятный момент)))

Comment: @PYTHON_KA, не стоит. :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#:%7E:text=%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%CC%81%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%CC%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%20(%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB.,%D0%A1%D0%B8)%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.): **Инстру́кция или опера́тор — наименьшая автономная часть языка программирования; команда или набор команд.**

Исходя из данного определения `print("Hello")` **будет инструкцией**.

Но при этом сам `print` всё ещё является **встроенной функцией**

Таким образом `print("Hello")` это **инструкция** которая вызывает **всторенную функцию** питона `print`, которая выводит строку на экран

Comment: А раньше print был оператором) Я имею в виду во втором питоне. В метках, правда, не указана версия, но, судя по примеру, спрашивают все-таки о третьем.

Comment: @Глеб В любом случае метод `print` всё равно существовал, а этот оператор был просто можно сказать макросом

Comment: да, про пайтон 3 спрашиваю)